# Akka - Test that function from test executed

Tags: scala, akka, scalatest, specs2

I have the following trait

```
trait MyTrait{

  def printHelloWorld(){
    println("hello world")
  }

}

case object SayHello

class MyActor extends Actor with MyTrait{

   def recieve = {
       case SayHello => printHelloWorld
   }
}
```

Now I'm trying to create Unit Test which test then Say Hello Object invokes printing hello message

```
"My Actor" should{
   "println hello msg if SayHello sent" in{
      val myTraitMock = mock[MyTrait]

      val myActor = system.actorOf(Props(new MyActor))
      myActor ! SayHello

      Thread.sleep(500)
      there was atLeastOne(myTraitMock).printHelloMessage
   }
}
```

However this unit test is always green. Even if I replace this method with simple println method.

Is there any other method to test such case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
trait MyActor extends Actor{self:MyTrait

   def recieve = {
       case SayHello => printHelloWorld
   }
}

class MyMainActor extends MyActor with MyTrait

"My Actor" should{
"println hello msg if SayHello sent" in{
     class MockActor extends MyActor with SomeMyTrait

      val x = new MockActor
      val myActor = system.actorOf(Props(x))
      myActor ! SayHello

      Thread.sleep(500)
      there was atLeastOne(x).printHelloMessage
   }
```

In general for actors, I am not a fan of above like testing. 
Akka [Test-kit](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/testing.html) is brilliant. I would highly recommend looking at it.

In which I would do :

```
trait MyTrait{

  def printHelloWorld(){
    println("hello world")

  }

}

case object SayHello
case object Printed

class MyActor extends Actor with MyTrait{

   def recieve = {
       case SayHello => printHelloWorld
                        sender ! Printed
   }
} 

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.testkit.{ TestProbe, ImplicitSender, TestKit }
import org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers
import org.scalatest.{ BeforeAndAfterAll, FunSuite }    
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class MyTest extends TestKit(ActorSystem("MyTest1"))
  with FunSuite
  with BeforeAndAfterAll
  with ShouldMatchers
  with ImplicitSender{

  override def afterAll() { system.shutdown() }
  test("MyTrait is called when triggered") {
    val x = TestProbe()
    val myActor = system.actorOf(Props(new MyActor))
    myActor.send(x, SayHello)
    x.expectMsg(Printed)

}
```

Comment: You need `libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.9.1" % "test"` and `libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.2.3"` as dependencies

Comment: that's nice I really like Akka-test, however MyActor should not return any message to sender. It just "fire and forget" I can extend it with other trait during the test that will return message to sender. This is the only Option I see.

Answer (score 1):

I know that it's an old question, but I had the same use case (fire and forget) and I came up with a simple solution using Probe:

```
case object SayHello

class MyActor(f: () => Unit) extends Actor{ // pass function as a parameter
  def receive = {
    case SayHello => f()
  }
}
```

now if you want to create a test:

```
  "test" {
    val probe = TestProbe()

    case object Executed

    def mockF():Unit = {
      println("test")
      probe.ref ! Executed
    }

    val testActor = TestActorRef(Props(new MyActor(mockF)))
    testActor ! SayHello
    //probe.expectMsg blocks the thread, so it'll wait for Executed message.
    probe.expectMsgPF(){case  Executed => 1}

  }
```

If you don't want to pass a function as a parameter then you can do the same thing with trait:

```
trait MyTraitImpl extends MyTrait{
  def printHelloWorld(){
    println("hello world")
      }
}

trait MyTrait{
  def printHelloWorld()
}

case object SayHello

class MyActor extends Actor{
  myTrait:MyTrait =>

  def receive = {
    case SayHello => printHelloWorld
  }
}
```

and test:

```
  "test" {
    val probe = TestProbe()

    case object Executed

    trait MyTraitMock extends MyTrait{
      def printHelloWorld(){
        println("hello world")

        probe.ref ! Executed
      }
    }

    val testActor = TestActorRef(Props(new MyActor() with MyTraitMock))
    testActor ! SayHello

    probe.expectMsgPF(){case  Executed => 1}

  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is feasible for all situations, but in my case I need to verify that a certain method of an injected object is called, so it works great. The test probe isn't necessary, at least not for Akka.NET, where you have access to the underlying test actor created by `TestKit`: `this.TestActor.Tell("foo");` and `this.ExpectMsg("foo");`.

Answer (score 0):

You can test on what is printed to the `EventFilter`. So if your actor would print message like that:

```
case _ => log.info(printMessage)
```

you can then test

```
EventFilter.info(start="hello world", occurences=1).intercept {
  MyActor ! SayHello
}
```